# Spring Data Pageable sort with nested property

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

in my Spring boot application I have an entity with an embedded primary key:

```java
public class MyEntity {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private MyPk pk;

}

@Embeddable
public class MyPk implements Serializable {
    
    private Integer key1;

    private Integer key2;

}
```

To sort the results using spring's Pageable object I have to call the rest service at: localhost?sort=pk.key1,asc

Is it possible, using JPA, to accept requests without pk? For example: localhost?sort=key1,asc

I'd like to be able to do this at the service level

Comment: I don't think it is possible unless you write some kind of custom [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html) which I have really no experience with to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to rewrite the sorts before passing them to the data layer:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class YourService {

    public static final Set<String> NESTED_PK_PROPERTIES = Set.of("key1", "key2");

    private final YourRepository repository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<YourResultType> search(final Pageable pageable) {
        // Correct sort properties if they refer to a nested property
        final Sort sort = Sort.by(
                pageable.getSort().get()
                        .map(order -> NESTED_PK_PROPERTIES.contains(order.getProperty()) ?
                                Sort.Order
                                        .by(String.format("%s_%s", "pk", order.getProperty()))
                                        .with(order.getDirection()) :
                                order)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        // Get manual changes matching the search criteria
        return repository.findAll(PageRequest.of(
                pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), sort));
    }

}
```